span inside p tag with textContent and style.color doesn't work
I have a problem with Javascript and HTML and I didn't find any solution yet.
The code is here:


const valide = document.querySelector("#valider");
valide.addEventListener("click", valider);

function valider() {;
    let showEmotion = document.getElementById("test").value;

    if (showEmotion === "happy") {
        document.getElementById("show").textContent = "I'm";
        document.getElementById("mood").textContent = "happy";
        document.getElementById("mood").style.color = "blue"
    }
    else if (showEmotion === "sad"){
        document.getElementById("show").textContent = "I'm";
        document.getElementById("mood").textContent = "sad";
        document.getElementById("mood").style.color = "blue"
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("show").textContent = "I'm";
        document.getElementById("mood").textContent = "happy";
        document.getElementById("mood").style.color = "blue"
    }
}
<body>
<h1>What's your mood ?</h1>
    <label>Mood: <input type="text" id="test" name="test" required minlength="2" maxlength="8" size="10" /></label>
    <button id="valider">Check</button>
    <hr/>
    <p id="show"><span id="mood"></span></p>
</body>



I don't know why I have only "I'm" when I click on the button and I haven't "I'm happy" or "I'm sad" with blue happy (or sad).
I want the complete sentence "I'm happy" or "I'm sad"
I think this is because the span tag is inside a p tag because I saw this can work with span tag only If I remember but I don't why it doesn't work inside a p tag.
Maybe because the span tag in an inline-level element and p is a block-element ?

Check your dev console for errors. Also, <h1>...</h1> should be inside the body tag.

I think you are right in your assumption that it is because span tag in an inline-level element and p is a block-element.

Yes, silly mistake, I will edit thanks mykaf !


I think this is because the span tag is inside a p tag

Yes, but perhaps not for the reason you think.  Since the id="mood" element is inside the id="show" element, then when you do this:
document.getElementById("show").textContent = "I'm";

You effectively clobber that content.  At that point the id="mood" element no longer exists.  So the very next line produces an error:
document.getElementById("mood").textContent = "happy";

You can observe this error on your browser's development console.
Instead of nesting the target tags inside each other and having to worry about maintaining their content, just use two elements nested inside a container.  Edit the contents of those two elements, leaving the container as-is.  For example:


const valide = document.querySelector("#valider");
valide.addEventListener("click", valider);

function valider() {;
    let showEmotion = document.getElementById("test").value;

    if (showEmotion === "happy") {
        document.getElementById("show").textContent = "I'm";
        document.getElementById("mood").textContent = "happy";
        document.getElementById("mood").style.color = "blue"
    }
    else if (showEmotion === "sad"){
        document.getElementById("show").textContent = "I'm";
        document.getElementById("mood").textContent = "sad";
        document.getElementById("mood").style.color = "blue"
    }

    else {
        document.getElementById("show").textContent = "I'm";
        document.getElementById("mood").textContent = "happy";
        document.getElementById("mood").style.color = "blue"
    }
}
<h1>What's your mood ?</h1>
<body>
    <label>Mood: <input type="text" id="test" name="test" required minlength="2" maxlength="8" size="10" /></label>
    <button id="valider">Check</button>
    <hr/>
    <p><span id="show"></span> <span id="mood"></span></p>
</body>




Thanks David, It works, but I have juste one question : Can I use twice the same id for the span tag ? I mean, this isn't a "bad pratice" ?

When you want several elements with the same identity - the same design, instead of using id, use class

Ok I thought about that too, thanks Agota !

I think this problem is because of textContent property, and you should use innerHTML property instead of that.
for example instead of this code:
 if (showEmotion === "happy") {
document.getElementById("show").textContent = "I'm";
document.getElementById("mood").textContent = "happy";
document.getElementById("mood").style.color = "blue"

}
write this code:
     if (showEmotion === "happy") {
    document.getElementById("mood").innerHTML = "happy";
    document.getElementById("mood").style.color = "blue"
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "I'm" + document.getElementById("mood").innerHTML;

}

because when you write this code, the "span" element in the "p" element will be removed from "span" content :
document.getElementById("show").textContent = "I'm";
And you have to use innerHTML property to recognize HTML tags

I didn't talk about overwriting, in this method both span and p elements remain and the desired result is obtained.
Otherwise, there are better ways to do it.
